# Whether the wrapped C++ object of pyqt5 still exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, anki

I'm working on python3 code using PyQT5.

Sometime, I have a PyQT5 object **o**, and I want to know whether it wraps an object which have been deleted or not. Because, otherwise, when I try to access it, I get the following error "wrapped C/C++ object of type **foo** has been deleted".

My goal is too close all opened window, so if the object is closed already, it's perfect. I just need to detect windows which are still opened.

I know in an ideal word, I should keep track of opened/closed windows myself, so it should not be the problem. However, I'm not allowed to change the API, and our API don't require windows to do anything when they close, so I can't keep track without breaking some add-ons using the API.

Furthermore, if the answer can use the standard library, that would be great, thus I would not have to import other library in the add-on I'm writing, and it will allow it to stay small.

Comment: Why don't you just use a `try/except` to deal with that specific error? It will be safer than using something like `sip.isdeleted`, which is potentially prone to a race condition. EAFP is usually more Pythonic than LBYL.

Comment: @ekhumoro Great idea. For some reason, I thought only Exceptions could be catched, and that Errors are not exceptions. My bad. Thank you